# Effective Parental Control Solutions for Ubuntu: Recommendations and Setup Guide

Tags: parental-controls

I'm a parent concerned about my children's online safety while using Ubuntu. What are the best parental control solutions available for Ubuntu, and how can I set them up effectively? I'm particularly interested in user-friendly GUI applications that offer comprehensive control over internet access, application usage, and screen time management. Additionally, what are some practical tips for configuring these tools to ensure a safe and secure online environment for my children while using Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 22 or 23

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of the `Timekpr` Ubuntu app and Firefox parental controls. Here are the commands to install `Timekpr` through the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjasnik/ppa && sudo apt update && sudo apt install timekpr-next
```

Then search for `Timekpr` in the app menu and open the one that has "SU" in its beginning. You will see a GUI application where you can limit the time a user (your child) can use the PC.

Apps can only be installed by root user, so don't worry about that.

Read [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-and-unblock-websites-parental-controls-firef) about how to block websites with the use of parental filters.

Sadly, `Timekpr` **does not have over the internet controls**. You will have to physically configure everything.

Comment: Thank you John for sharing your insights! It's helpful to know about using Timekpr for managing screen time and Firefox parental controls for website filtering.

However, I'm also interested in implementing stricter controls to prevent access to specific websites and unauthorized installations of VPNs and other applications. If you have recommendations or additional tips on achieving these goals, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, @Wali. Here is [Logify](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/logify-parental-control/?utm_content=search&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=addons.mozilla.org), an extension that allows you to monitor your child's activity through the use of the logify app. There is also an extension called [Vblocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vblocker1/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) which blocks users without a set password from certain websites.

Comment: You can block websites that have a specific keyword in their URL with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url-keyword-blocker/) extension, and [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsguardian/) extension blocks sensitive search keywords (you can also add your own). So if a search phrase contains "VPN", the extension will block the results.

Comment: Hey @John Carter, thanks a lot. I've encountered another issue. I've configured all the extensions, but now I'm worried that my child might access the Firefox settings and disable them. Do you know how I can secure the extension settings or set up a password for them?

Comment: According to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1026175, you can install this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/public-fox/

Comment: This extension had a bug. When I set the password and blocked the addons page, then refreshed the browser and went to the addons page, it showed the prompt to enter the password. However, upon entering the password, it did not redirect me to that page

Comment: @Wali This seems to be a bug on your side. This extension has 2k users and 62 reveiws, most arepositive